# Extracting array of strings from _variant_t

Tags: c++, com, simulation

I am using OpenDSS with C++ to run power flow. I have established a COM interface from C++ to OpenDSS.

In the documentation of OpenDSS, it says that the list of bus names can be obtained by a function call that returns an array of strings containing the bus names. The data type of the return parameter is `_variant_t`, so I have to extract the array of strings using my own function. I have tried numerous methods but none seem to work. I have attached the C++ file for reference.

Here, I always get the result that the vector is empty when it should contain the list of strings that is the names of the buses.

The main contains the section where the circuit is created. `GetArrayOfStrings()` is a function to extract the array, once the circuit is created.

```
#import "C:\Program Files\OpenDSS\x64\OpenDSSengine.dll"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <comutil.h>
#include <vector>
#include "tchar.h"
#include "CaseSelect.h"

using namespace std;
std::vector<std::wstring> GetArrayOfStrings(const _variant_t& varData) 
{
    std::vector<std::wstring> result;

    try {
        // Extract the array from _variant_t
        SAFEARRAY* psa = V_ARRAY(&varData);

        // Get the lower and upper bounds of the array
        long lLBound, lUBound;
        SafeArrayGetLBound(psa, 1, &lLBound);
        SafeArrayGetUBound(psa, 1, &lUBound);

        // Iterate through the array
        for (long i = lLBound; i <= lUBound; ++i) {
            // Variable to store each element
            _variant_t element;

            // Get the element at index i
            SafeArrayGetElement(psa, &i, &element);

            // Convert the element to a string and add it to the result vector
            result.push_back(static_cast<const wchar_t*>(_bstr_t(element)));
        }
    }
    catch (const _com_error& e) {
        // Handle the extraction error
        // e.g., print an error message or throw an exception
        // You might also want to log more details about the error for debugging
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        //throw std::runtime_error("Error extracting array of strings: " + std::string(e.ErrorMessage()));
    }

    return result;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    try
    {
        OpenDSSengine::IDSSPtr DSSObj;
        DSSObj.CreateInstance(uuidof(OpenDSSengine::DSS));
        OpenDSSengine::ITextPtr DSSText;
        OpenDSSengine::ICircuitPtr DSSCircuit;
        OpenDSSengine::ISolutionPtr DSSSolution;
        if (DSSObj->Start(0))
        {
            cout << "OpenDSS Loaded" << endl;
            DSSText = DSSObj->Text;
            DSSCircuit = DSSObj->ActiveCircuit;
            DSSSolution = DSSCircuit->Solution;
            cout << DSSObj->Version << endl;
            DSSText->Command = "Clear";
            DSSText->Command = "New Circuit.TheveninEquivalent basekv=115 bus1=100";
            //std::vector<unsigned short> Y_matrix = DSSCircuit->SystemY;
            //DSSCircuit->SetActiveElement("Circuit.TheveninEquivalent");
            DSSText->Command = "New Transformer.t1 phases=3 windings=2 xhl=5";
            DSSText->Command = "~ wdg=1 bus=100 conn=delta kv=115 kva=5000";
            DSSText->Command = "~ wdg=1 bus=200 conn=delta kv=4.16 kva=5000";
            DSSText->Command = "New Line.Ln phases=2 bus1=200.1.2 bus2=300.1.2 length=0.3 units=km";
            DSSText->Command = "~ rmatrix = (0.8261 | 0.1284 0.8226)";
            DSSText->Command = "~ xmatrix = (0.8370 | 0.2853 0.8431)";
            DSSText->Command = "~ cmatrix = (7.7626 | -1.4833 7.6902)";
            DSSSolution->Solve();
            DSSText->Command = "Show Y";
            //auto busindex = DSSCircuit->SetActiveBus("200.1.2");
            _variant_t varData = DSSCircuit->GetAllBusNames();
            try {
                std::vector<std::wstring> strings = GetArrayOfStrings(varData);

                // Now 'strings' contains the array of strings
                for (const auto& str : strings) {
                    std::wcout << str << std::endl;
                }
            }
            catch (const std::exception& ex) 
            {
                // Handle the exception
                std::cerr << "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
            }

            //DSSText->Command = "New Transformer.t1 phases=3 windings=2 xhl=5";
        };
    }
    catch (_com_error e)
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("Error: %S\n", e.Description());
        printf("Error: %S\n", e.ErrorMessage());
    }
}
```

`varData.vt` has the decimal value of 8200, which in hex is 0x2008, which is an array of strings as per `VARENUM` documentation in MSDN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `SafeArrayGetElement()` is wrong.

For one thing, you are not checking its return value for failure. For instance, if it can't allocate memory for a new `BSTR` to copy the retrieved string into.

More importantly, you have an array of `BSTR` elements (`varData.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_BSTR`), not an array of `VARIANT` elements (`varData.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT`), so you need to receive each element as a `BSTR`, not as a `VARIANT`, eg:

```
_bstr_t element;

HRESULT hres = SafeArrayGetElement(psa, &i, element.GetAddress());
if (FAILED(hres))
    _com_raise_error(hres);

result.push_back(static_cast<const wchar_t*>(element));
```

Alternatively, you can avoid `SafeArrayGetElement()` altogether (and thus any unnecessary `BSTR` allocations) by using `SafeArrayAccessData()` instead to access the underlying `BSTR[]` array directly, eg:

```
BSTR *elements = NULL;
HRESULT hres = SafeArrayAccessData(psa, reinterpret_cast<void HUGEP **>(&elements));
if (FAILED(hres))
    _com_raise_error(hres);

for (long i = lLBound; i <= lUBound; ++i) {
    result.push_back(elements[i-lLBound]);
}

// or simply:
// result.insert(result.end(), elements, elements+(lUBound-lLBound)+1);

SafeArrayUnaccessData(psa);
```

Either way, it would also be a good idea to validate that you are actually receiving a `VT_ARRAY | VT_BSTR` variant as input before you begin processing it, eg:

```
std::vector<std::wstring> GetArrayOfStrings(const _variant_t& varData) 
{
    ...
    if (varData.vt != (VT_ARRAY | VT_BSTR))
        _com_raise_error(E_INVALIDARG);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I see where I did wrong. This definitely pushed me in the right direction! I have added all the error handling, and now I'm stuck with another error with the line

`HRESULT hres = SafeArrayGetElement(psa, &i, &element);`

Through debugging I see that the element's(_bstr_t) internal structure m_wstr and m_str has error reading characters of string even though hres is S_OK.
I don't think that is the problem of the code however.
Thanks!

Comment: You can't use the `&` operator to get a pointer to the `_bstr_t`'s internal `BSTR`, you must use the `_bstr_t::GetAddress()` method instead, as shown in my example: `SafeArrayGetElement(psa, &i, element.GetAddress());`

Comment: Wow, works beautifully!
Thank you so much for the help. Appreciate it!